# Inductive Proof decimal representation of real numbers by taking the limit of a recursive series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I have a homework problem, the solution has been published and I understand it and am not looking for that.
Rather I've hit an impassé that contradicts the solution and I would be very grateful if you can point out where I'm making the mistake.

The problem: Decimal representation of real numbers
For $ b \in \Bbb{N} $ and $ b >= 2$ and $ x \in [0, 1) $
We define $x_1, x_2, .... $ recursively as:
$x_1 = max ({k \in \Bbb{Z}\space | \space k <= bx} )$

and $$ x_n = [b^n(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k})]$$

So there are several parts of the problem and in one we have to prove an inequality by induction

Here is where I failed because I ended up with $x_{n+1} = 0 $ somehow:

$$x_{n+1} = [b^{n+1}(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {x_k}{b^k})] = \space [b^{n+1}(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k} \space - \frac{x_n}{b^n})]$$

$$ = [b^{n+1}(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k}) \space - \space b^{n+1}\frac{x_n}{b^n}]$$
$$ = [b^{n+1}(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k}) \space - \space b{x_n}]$$
$$ = [bb^{n}(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k}) \space - \space b{x_n}]$$
$$ = [b(b^{n}(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k})) \space - \space b{x_n}]$$ grouping the elements
$$ = [b(x_n) \space - \space b{x_n}]$$
$$ = 0 $$

which is obviously wrong?
Thank you very much for your help. Usually I have an idea where something could be wrong, but this time I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you substitute $x_n$ for $(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{x_k}{b^k})b^n$. Notice that you are neglecting the integer part.

Comment: Hi @Dude, thank you, I am so sorry, I went over this a few times again. I can't follow, which Integer part do you mean?

Comment: The square brackets in your definition of $x_n$, the floor function...

Comment: thanks, these are just normal brackets, not the floor function.

Comment: It is the floor function!, Check out the proof

Comment: oh I see now, thank you very much, I think we were supposed to show that this is the floor function, maybe, because we have to show by induction that $0 <= x_n = [b^n(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {x_k}{b^k})] - x_n  <= 1 $ which should follow from it being the floor function. Thanks a lot!